# I can't understand SpriteKit's rotation system

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to rotate sprites with SKAction.rotateToAngle. For example:

```
rotate = SKAction.rotateToAngle(desiredAngle, duration: 1.0)
sprite.runAction(rotate)
```

But it didn't work as expected. The sprites rotates in a different way. By trying and trying I've found out that this is the rotation system adopted by SpriteKit:

[image]

Now I don't know why they decided to adopt this coordinate system but it's pretty counter-intuitive. How can I convert between this system and the normal one?
And by the way how can I rotate the sprites clockwise?

Comment: By "normal", do you mean degrees, or do you mean having 0 rad in the same place as 0 deg is shown on your chart?

Comment: The docs say "Creates an action that rotates the node counterclockwise to an absolute angle." You could try `rotateByAngle(_:duration:)` instead, or maybe `rotateToAngle(_:duration:shortestUnitArc:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

[image]

> An angle of 0 radians specifies the positive x axis. A positive angle
>   is in the counterclockwise direction.

To rotate an object by 90 degrees counterclockwise, do this:

```
let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(M_PI/2.0), duration: 5.0)
```

To rotate an object by 90 degrees clockwise, do this:

```
let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI/2.0), duration: 5.0)
```

Or instead of using negatives (-90 degrees), you can specify the angle as a positive value(270 degrees), and use `rotateToAngle(_:duration:shortestUnitArc:)` method which rotates the object in direction which results in the smallest rotation.

```
 let action = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(2 * M_PI - M_PI/2.0), duration: 5, shortestUnitArc: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.2**

To rotate an object by 180 degree clockwise:

```
let spin = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -.pi, duration: 10)
```

To rotate an object by 180 degree counterclockwise:

```
let spin = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: .pi, duration: 10)
```

To 90 degrees, divide by 2:

```
let spin = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: -.pi/2, duration: 10)
let spin = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: .pi/2, duration: 10)
```

[image]